# Converting an []slice to an []map with same keys for every slice

Tags: go

Hi I am trying to convert an []slice to a []map with the same keys for every map value.

The use case is the following: suppose you are trying to parse an excel sheet to a map. You know the header column as a slice of strings. You then get the rows in the format [][]string. To get a map you must set the header values to each item in each row.

My current implementation is the following

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    header := []string{"first", "second", "third"}
    rows := [][]string{{"1.1", "1.2", "1.3"}, {"2.1", "2.2", "2.3"}, {"3.1", "3.2", "3.3"}}

    length := len(header)

    var values []map[string]interface{}
    for _, row := range rows {
        dict := map[string]interface{}{}
        for i, val := range row {
            if i < length {
                dict[header[i]] = val
            }
        }
        values = append(values, dict)
    }
    fmt.Println(values)
}
```

Go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/Ags779GVtD7

The issue here is complexity as you have to loop through all of the rows and then set the keys to each row by looping again.

Would be grateful for suggestions of a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no more efficient way to do this. If you want to put `n` elements in a map you will have to do `O(n)` operations. And your double loop results in `n` insert call.